# Events on PopupPanel

Tags: java, gwt

I have a PopupPanel and am trying to do something whenever it is mouse clicked. For this, I have created a ClickHandler as follows:

```
ClickHandler handler = new ClickHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
     System.out.println("I have been clicked...");
   }
};
```

and then add my handler to the panel as follows:

```
PopupPanel panel = new PopupPanel();
// assign values to panel...
panel.addHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
```

My event handler never gets called. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do

```
    panel.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK); 
    panel.addHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Comment: Vladimir - Thank you, this helped me.